# Redirect URL except subpages

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect everything under `www.mywebsite/asd/` except for three URLs and any subcontent, `www.mywebsite/asd/A/`, `www.mywebsite/asd/B/` and `www.mywebsite/asd/A/`.

I tried the following pattern, but it seems to be faulty:

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/asd/((?!A/|B/|C/).)* /asd/new-target/index.html`

The regular expression does what I want, when I test it in a regex editor. But in htaccess it doesn't work. What do I have to change?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/asd/(?!A/|B/|C/|new-target/)(.*)$ /asd/new-target/index.html
```

And test it after clearing your browser cache. Make sure this is your first rule in site root .htaccess and there is no .htaccess in `/asd/` directory.

---

Alternatively you can use this `mod_rewrite` rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ads/(?:A|B|C|new-target)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?asd(?:/.*)?$ /asd/new-target/index.html [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: I tried your code, but when I use it this way, I get internal server error 500.

Comment: I think my server doesn't allow lookaheads. Is there an alternative without using lookaheads?

Comment: What is your Apache version?

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately my server still seems to have a problem with this. I'm sure this is would normally work, but I get an internal server error again. Is there a way to check expressions are allowed on my server an which are not?

Comment: To get better help you need to answer questions raised. I asked earlier **What is your Apache version?** now for 500 you need to find out where your Apache error.log is and check the relevant log entry for cause of 500 error.